# can't import django_tables2l

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

Hi I am new at Django and I have tried my best to understand it but I still have a long way to go. I am working on a project in which I want to use django tables2 to create a HTML tables. I have been trying to import the django tables for days now and still no luck....Please help me.

I get this error when trying to `import django_tables2

```
$ python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 10 2012, 23:31:26) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import django_tables2
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "build\bdist.win32\egg\django_tables2\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
File "build\bdist.win32\egg\django_tables2\tables.py", line 4, in <module>
File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
if DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS not in settings.DATABASES:
File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 184, in inner
self._setup()
File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 40, in _setup
raise ImportError("Settings cannot be imported, because environment variable %s is              undefined." % ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE)
ImportError: Settings cannot be imported, because environment variable     DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE is undefined.
```

and when i import from forms.py i get error unresolved import. please please help me and show me step by step how to do it correctly.. thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to go inside the Project i.e. you django_table2 where you will find the manage.py file. Try loading it in the shell using:

```
python manage.py shell
```

This would set the required django and python environment. After this you would be able to import project in the Python Path. So, django_tables2 if you are using Linux OS could be found inside /usr/local/lib/python2.*/dist_packages/
All you are required to do is from the Shell import it using,

```
from django_tables2 import *
```

Now the imports would obviously depend on what you are trying to accomplish. You may want to check this tutorial out.
http://django-tables2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Comment: thank u @Raunak. i have a project called rehab and i did like to use django_tables2 inside my project rehab so that i may be able to create html tables. so do i have to be in rehab project and use manage.py and load the python manage.py shell?

Comment: @NewbieDjango: You will need to load the environmental for your project rehab and then, normally you may import the django_tables2 in to the shell. Just by saying from django_tables2 import *

Comment: i am a bit noob here so sorry...how am i suppose to that???i think that is the part i am lost....how do i load to the environment???can you please show me step by step...i would be very much appreciated if you could do that....thanks a million....

Comment: thank you so much@Raunak Agarwal.......You made my weekend brighter....I made it...i can import......thank you a billion....:D

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention you would need to include the application in to your django installed_apps inside the settings.py.

Answer (score 0):

The error:

> `ImportError`: Settings cannot be imported, because environment variable     `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` is undefined.

means that `django_tables2` is only importable when you're in a Django context so that it knows what your project settings are and so on, not just in a general Python context.

Try it from `manage.py shell` instead, which sets the required `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` variable for you.

Comment: thank you for you quick reply. @Dougal. how do i want to know that which sets? i am totally lost here..so sorry. i am now in manage.shell and what should i do then???thanks..